# How can Lua support Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, lua

How can Lua support MongoDB?
I installed [Mongol](https://github.com/bigplum/lua-resty-mongol), it's not work, just hint me "connect failed: localhost could not be resolved (3: Host not found)".

Resolved: the code

`mongo = require('resty.mongol')

conn = mongo:new()

ok, err = conn:connect('127.0.0.1')`

if not ok then
    ngx.say("connect failed: "..err)
end

local db = conn:new_db_handle("weidian")
col = db:get_col("channel")
r = col.find_one({})
for k, v in pairs(r) do
    ngx.say(k)
end
conn:close()

Comment: did you try the ip address?

Comment: @Dreamwalker aha, it's work. I just tried localhost.bad

Comment: Did you pass `localhost` as a string or just a variable?

Comment: as a string. like this  conn:connect('localhost', 27017)

Comment: Can you put your code in the question too?

Comment: @DreamEater it's work now. I pass '127.0.0.1' as a string to connect() function and it work fine.

Comment: @DreamEater How can I make this question to resolved?

Comment: It must work with localhost too. Are you on Windows or *nix system? For the second question, I'd request @Dreamwalker to put his comment as a reply.

Comment: Oh man, It's not work really if I put 'localhost' as a string to connect() function. I'm using UbuntuOS.

Comment: the code:

    conn = mongo:new()
    ok, err = conn:connect('127.0.0.1')
    if not ok then
        ngx.say("connect failed: "..err)
    end

    local db = conn:new_db_handle("weidian")
    col = db:get_col("channel")
    r = col:find_one({})
    for k,v in pairs(r) do
        ngx.say(k)
    end

Comment: Were you providing port when using localhost?

Comment: @DreamEater this.<br />

conn:connect('localhost', 27017);

Comment: It's always a good habit to put your code along with the code. (^_^)

Comment: Like this? I reedit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to mongodb, you don't need to specify custom value to port.

So, your code should be one of:

```
conn:connect( 'localhost' )
```

or

```
conn:connect( '127.0.0.1' )
```

Comment: Aha, Thanks for Dream Eater

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing the IP address instead?  (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with lua-resty-mongol using the ip for the connection works just fine you may also want so look at the forks because the original repo has not been updated for quite a while